# Increasing max execution time for drupal commons install

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I'm attempting to install drupal commons on amazon web services Ubuntu server. When I arrive at the install page, I get the following errors:

> PHP Max Execution Time    30
>   Your PHP execution time is too low, please
>   set it greater than or equal to 120 seconds.
>
> OpCache memory    64
>   OpCache is installed but is not enough space to
>   successfully install Drupal Commons. Change the capacity to at least
>   96.

I was told that I need to access my php.ini file. I'm an absolute beginner and have no idea how I should do that. Not sure if this is something I can fix via SSH, AWS management console or phpmyadmin.

Thanks!

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/356968/find-the-correct-php-ini-file how to find the php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Simple way : 
Add to settings.php the following line :

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

Otherwise you can create a file  (like phpinfo.php) in root directory of drupal who contains phpinfo() function :

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

You'll see all information about your configuration, it features the path of php.ini who used. So, you have the path, you can edit right file and find key max_execution_time to increase it. Finaly , stop and restart httpd/apache.

```
service apache2 restart
```